# Batch convert Apple Pages files to Microsoft Word doc files

Tags: ms-office, pages, numbers, iwork

How can I convert a large number of Pages and Numbers files into corresponding MS Office format in a quick manner.

Answer (score 3):

iWork Converter can batch convert Pages files to doc without script.
Also can convert Numbers files to xls.

http://tyorex.com/iWorkConverter

Answer (score 2):

Paste this into an Automator run AppleScript.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    --Select from where you will pick up the pages files
    set theSourceFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select folder with original pages files :"
    --Do it
    tell application "Finder"
        set theNames to name of files of theSourceFolder ¬
            whose name extension is "pages"
    end tell

    --Select where the files will go
    set theDestinationFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select folder where files will go :"

    -- How many files to export
    set item_count to (get count of items in theNames)

    --Get files and export them
    repeat with i from 1 to item_count

        set current_file to item i of theNames -- get a file
        set lean_file to text 1 thru -7 of current_file & ".docx" -- change the originalfile (.pages) to a .MS Word name
        set out_file to (theDestinationFolder as Unicode text) & (lean_file) -- get the fully qualified output name
        set in_file to (theSourceFolder as Unicode text) & (current_file) -- get the fully qualified input file name

        tell application "Pages"
            set mydoc to open file in_file -- open input file in Pages
            export mydoc to file out_file as Microsoft Word --do the exporting
            close mydoc saving no -- close the original file without saving
        end tell

    end repeat


    display dialog "done" -- Job done

    return input

end run
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Automator and some third-party actions such as:

https://www.ghostotter.com/pages-automator-actions

...to make a droplet or service to do the job.

For example:

Open Automator from your Applications folder
Make a new Application (File>New>Application)

Next, assuming you have the actions mentioned above, drag in the following actions from the Pages library (in the left hand column):

- Open Document(s)
- Export as PDF (remembering to select "All Documents"    from the drop
  down
- Close Document(s)(again, remembering to select    "All Documents"
  from the drop down

It should look something like this:

[image]

Save your Automator app somewhere you can get to it easily (e.g. your Desktop) and simply drop Pages documents onto it as and when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use my app [Docxtor](https://docxtor.de). It lets you convert whole folders of documents and will even reproduce complete folder structures, something which is difficult to achieve by AppleScript.

(Disclaimer: I am the developer of this app!)