# Catch-22 for old Pages version on ancient old MBP (late-2008)

Tags: upgrade, crash, pages, iwork

after having worked perfectly fine for 9 years, my Pages (iWork '08) keeps crashing lately and, as of today, crashes when I do the simplest actions. I operate on a late-2008 MBP which I've upgraded to OSX El Capitan. Now, I can't upgrade to High Sierra, because as per the spec requirements in the App Store, it requires a MBP from mid-2010 or later. However, I also can't simply update to an older Pages version because I still have iWork '08.

I've downloaded iWork '09 Trial in order to then upgrade to the most recent pages version available for El Capitan, but after clicking on "Free Trial" and entering my e-mail address, it keeps crashing, too. Switching to Word isn't really an option, considering all of my text-written files are in .pages format.

Is there anyone who could help? Thanks.

Comment: With Pages closed, backup _com.apple.iWork.Pages.LSSharedFileList.plist_ and _com.apple.iWork.Pages.plist_ in _/Users/<name>/Library/Preferences/_. Then delete these two files and try opening Pages. Does it still crash?

Comment: I'd recommend getting out of .pages into .doc.  See  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124263/batch-convert-pages-files-to-doc